# Referencing a join table with no code in a hibernate query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I have searched everything I can think of and read the hibernate docs and haven't been able to answer this question, so I'm turning here.

I have an InboundFaxQueue class. It has a many to many relationship with my InboundFaxDocumentInfo class. So, InboundFaxQueue has the following definition.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "InboundFaxQueue_InboundFaxDocumentInfos",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "inbound_fax_queue_id", nullable = false),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "document_id", nullable = false))
@Where(clause = PROCESSED_FILTER)
private final Set<InboundFaxDocumentInfo> faxDocumentInfos = new HashSet<>();
```

So now I want to write a query that will return the InboundFaxQueue object with a particular document_id. My last clumsy attempt, which wouldn't compile, is this:

```
<query name="FaxDocument.getFaxQueuesContainingDocument">
    <![CDATA[
    SELECT ifq
      FROM com.casenet.domain.docmgmt.InboundFaxQueue ifq
            WHERE ifq.faxDocumentInfos.document_id = :documentId
    ]]>
</query>
```

Not sure where to go next.

Comment: Not try but I think you need a join in this situation:
`SELECT ifq FROM InboundFaxQueue ifq join fetch  ifq.faxDocumentInfos x WHERE x.document_id = :documentId`

Comment: Failed, but with nothing specific telling me what's wrong. :(

Comment: It was long time when I define query in xml, but I think cdata is not necessery, query is not an embedded xml, maybe it parsed as the part of the query? Dunno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of trial and error, here's the query that finally worked.

```
<query name="FaxDocument.getFaxQueuesContainingDocument">
    <![CDATA[
        SELECT ifq
        FROM InboundFaxQueue AS ifq
        JOIN ifq.faxDocumentInfos AS fdi
            WHERE fdi.id = :documentId
    ]]>
</query>
```

Thanks for all who helped.